# PHPUnit get good feedback from the test

Tags: php, phpunit, automated-tests

this question for me is to found a way to improve my test. When i test my code, usually I use this code:

```
 $this->assertContains('textExample', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

when the test get OK all is right, but when the test fail the feedback from phpunit is so heavy, because php unit echo to terminal all the page into have search the textExample. 
I would filter $client->getResponse()->getContent()) and search textExample in the precise part of site where i search it (div, h2...) and not have that heavy feedback form phpunit.

I hope I was clear, if not i'll try to re-explain.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use either `tearDwon()` or `onNotSuccessfulTest()` methods. This way you could handle the error and filter if you need.

For instance you could try something like this to start:

```
public function onNotSuccessfulTest($e) {
    // inspect $e to get the information you need, for ie:
    print_r(get_class_methods($e)); die();
    parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
}
```

Check [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) for more information.

Comment: and which is the way to use this? i think something like $client->getResponse()->getContent()->filter('div .inThisDiv')

Comment: @NicolaPez I updated the answer with get_class_methods, so you can check what methods are available on $e

Comment: @NicolaPez I did not see the update, is this still relevant for you? Did my answer help?

Comment: i'm not already try your solution, also if is not what I thought. I didn't tried becouse is a little fix I want use in my code, but not a core things. I'll try in the next week, i'll tell to you if your solution is good for me! thx